# how to use email tags(for track emails) in mandrill using php

Tags: php

I read about tags in email, from which we can track our emails by using some email providers like mandrill.
I want to know how can I add tags using php, is there any function?

i have used 
$mail->setHeader('X-MC-Tags','tag_name');

Comment: And is there anything not working with the given code?

Comment: i dont have any idea, what to use for adding tags

Comment: What have you tried to find that out? What exactly do these "tags" mean? Is there any documentation about it?

Comment: https://www.mailgun.com/blog/tags-explained-gaining-useful-insights-from-email-segmentation

Comment: And what is wrong by using the documentation posted at https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#tagging that tells you how to add tags?

Comment: I dont want to use it for api, I want to use it with signup emails

Comment: i never used tags before, pls let me know how can i use it

Comment: I don't get what you want to use: what should these tags be? What makes you think that any mail reader triggers anything for you when using them?

Comment: have you used any mail provider, like mandrill or sendgrid?